# Postgresql: Trying to get Average of Counts for the last 10 ten days

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

```
Select avg(last_10_count) AS last_10_avg
(Select count(*)
from dim_user
where effective_date ::date > current_date -10
group by effective_date ::date) AS last_10_count
```

When I just run the inline query, I get the desired result, but when I run the whole query it throws the following error:

```
ERROR: function avg(record) does not exist
LINE 1: Select avg(last_10_count) AS last_10_avg
HINT: NO function matches the given name and arguement types.
      You might need to add explicit type casts.
************Error***************
ERROR: function avg(record)  does not exit
SQL state: 42883
```

Comment: what you exactly want ? COUNT(*) will give you only one value.

Comment: I want to count data for the past 10 days. That's the reason I added group by effective_date ::date function.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this one

```
Select avg(last_10_count) AS last_10_avg from 
(Select count(*) as last_10_count
from dim_user
where effective_date::date  > current_date -10
group by effective_date :: date) Z
```

Comment: Could someone link to the documentation explaining what the `Z` is meant to represent?

Comment: Z doesn't influence the query here. It's an alias given to the subquery because sql needs it in order to be able to temporarily store the subquery's results. More exactly, a subquery without an alias is invalid in the same way a table without a name is.

Comment: as Z , is the same